Circuit to drive a high power high frequency electromagnetic coil
I'm trying to design a circuit that can drive an air-core coil with an inductance of 45uH. The coil has a resistance of 0.15 Ohm measured at 50 kHz. The circuit should be able to push up to 100A through the coil. The coil is water-cooled, so heat dissipation is not an issue. Driving current waveform will be a phase-modulated sine wave (carrier frequency up to 50 kHz; modulation frequency up to 100 Hz). What kind of circuit/amplifier topology would be suitable for this? and what kind of power supply?

45 uH @ 50 kHz and 100A will require 1300 V and 130 kW peak power. Is this what you expect ?

Are you able to tune the coil and use a single frequency at a time? That will make an order of magnitude or more difference to the driver requirements.

@jp314 if I understand correctly, then since the voltage and current would be out of phase by almost 90 degrees in the coil due to the impedance being dominated by its inductance, the peak real power would be only around 1.5 kW due to the coil resitance. Is that correct?

@Neil_UK I could potentially tune the coil to a single frequency with a series capacitor if absolutely necessary, but I wanted to explore first if there are any feasible options for driving the coil in an untuned circuit and maintaining flexibility in the carrier frequency.

@KhaledNasr Everything is feasible, how much money have you got? Tuning saves you a factor of 10 or 100 in the volts x amps of the driving circuit. Without tuning, you have to drive the inductance. With tuning, you drive the residual resistance.

@Neil_UK assuming that cost is not a factor, what would you suggest as a way to drive the inductance directly?

A 45 uH coil at 50 kHz has an impedance of about 14 Ω. If you want to push 100 A peak through that, it would require about 1400 V. If that 100 A figure you ask for is RMS, it will be 2 kV peak. This is a VA rating, the actual power you have to deliver is much lower, given by the circuit losses.
Driving it from an H-bridge means its supply only needs to be just over 1400 V or 2 kV. A quick search online for 'high voltage IGBT' yields lots of hits for devices of 4 to 6 kV, for many 100s of amps (Infineon for example), but they would be marginal for speed (Toff in the many μs). You would have to experiment with thrashing the gate drives, or spend some time searching for faster devices. These devices are aimed at the traction and AC supply market, where your speed is not really needed.
When series tuned, the drive circuit sees only the residual resistance of the coil. If you allow that the RF resistance is higher, and add in a bit of loss in the tuning capacitor and the wiring, you might need to drive only 0.5 Ω. At 100 A rms, this is 70 V peak. There are plenty of fast FETs with more than that voltage rating made for direct-to-line power supplies, you will have no trouble at all finding and driving suitable devices.
The tuning capacitor will be non-trivial, it's got to support 2 kV at 100 A, but at least it's passive. It would be useful to make it from many small capacitors (an MMC, multi module capacitor, as it's known in the Tesla coiling community) to get the current handling. It would also allow serial/parallel reconfiguration to get higher capacitance where lower frequencies and so lower voltages are needed. For instance, two 1 kV 440 nF capacitors in series would resonate 45 uH at 50 kHz and withstand 2 kV, while in parallel they would resonate 45 uH at 25 kHz and stand the 1 kV needed. I'm a great fan of 6 or 12 sub-modules, which allows for great flexibility for series/parallel rearrangement, for instance 12:1, 6:2, 4:3, 3:4, 2:6, and 1:12. A few extra sub-modules allows for trimming these nice arrangements up or down to cover other frequencies.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
